# google maps html code in infowindow instead of pure tekst

Tags: google-maps

I just found this awesome code on stack overflow. It opens an infowindow by pressing a button. But the problems is. Instead of the info window only 'marker1'  I want to implement html code instead. But i fails when i do that.  I only want to implement an easy code like an h1 and a un list. But it only approves pure tekst.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function infoOpen(i)
        {

            google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
        }
        var gmarkers = [];
        var markers = [];
        markers = [
            ['0', 'Marker 1', 13.988719, 100.617909],
            ['1', 'Marker 2', 13.662811, 100.43758],
            ['2', 'Marker 3', 13.744961, 100.535073],
            ['3','Marker 4', 13.801981, 100.613864],
            ['4', 'Marker 5', 13.767507, 100.644024]];

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myOptions = {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/marker.png',
            new google.maps.Size(65, 32),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(18, 42));
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var marker, i;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]);
                var content = markers[i][1];
                bounds.extend(pos);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map
                });
                gmarkers.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, content));
            }


            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center
        }
        #map {
            width:640px;
            height: 480px;
            border:6px solid #6f5f5e;
            margin:20px auto 30px auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('0');">mark 1</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('1');">mark 2</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('2');">mark 3</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('3');">mark 4</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('4');">mark 5</a>

        <div id="map">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is what i want, but it doesnt work:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function infoOpen(i)
        {

            google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
        }
        var gmarkers = [];
        var markers = [];
        markers = [
            ['0', '<h1>title</h1><p>tekst</p>', 13.988719, 100.617909],
            ['1', 'Marker 2', 13.662811, 100.43758],
            ['2', 'Marker 3', 13.744961, 100.535073],
            ['3','Marker 4', 13.801981, 100.613864],
            ['4', 'Marker 5', 13.767507, 100.644024]];

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myOptions = {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/marker.png',
            new google.maps.Size(65, 32),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(18, 42));
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var marker, i;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]);
                var content = markers[i][1];
                bounds.extend(pos);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map
                });
                gmarkers.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, content));
            }


            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center
        }
        #map {
            width:640px;
            height: 480px;
            border:6px solid #6f5f5e;
            margin:20px auto 30px auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('0');">mark 1</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('1');">mark 2</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('2');">mark 3</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('3');">mark 4</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('4');">mark 5</a>

        <div id="map">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You've posted a working example, you better post your attempt that didn't work

Comment: the 2nd part works for me too, when your problem is the size/display of the InfoWindow: this is a known bug for a long time now, see [**Bug: InfoWindow resizes incorrectly and has scrollbars**](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5713) (maybe you find there a suitable approach)

Comment: Interdasting!! It works. Grazy bug

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euvwej1t/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain which is the JS error thrown? I use something like this

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: data,
        maxWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 400,
        mId: marcador.mId
    });

    infoWindow.open(map, marcador);
```

Where data is any HTML string you would like to put. For example:

```
<h1>Title</h1> <p>Text</p>
```

Comment: js error 404 not found.   I just tried to implement your ideer. it said the same.  How would you implement it.